# How to install tomcat 9?

Tags: server, 15.10, tomcat

I can't  install **tomcat 9** in ubuntu-15.10.Can anyone tell me the process how to install tomcat 9 in ubuntu-15.10?

Comment: When you say you can't do it, what exactly have you tried? There are instructions everywhere, such as these: http://tecadmin.net/install-tomcat-9-on-ubuntu/ which should work.

Answer (score 9):

You can find the instructions for install [right here](http://tecadmin.net/install-tomcat-9-on-ubuntu/).

They run through 4 steps to install, with superseding steps to run tomcat.  Here they are:

## 1. Verify Java

Tomcat 9 is designed to run on Java SE 8 or later.  To check your version, run this command:

```
java -version
```

For instructions on installing java, visit [this link](http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/).

## 2. Download Tomcat Archive

Download the archive using these commands or download it from tomcat's [official download page](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi).

```
cd /opt
wget http://www.us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.0.M1/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M1.tar.gz
tar xzf apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M1.tar.gz
mv apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M1 tomcat9
```

## 3. Configure Environment Variables

Before starting, you'll have to define your `CATALINA_HOME` variable:

```
echo "export CATALINA_HOME="/opt/tomcat9"" >> /etc/environment
echo "export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"" >> /etc/environment
echo "export JRE_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre"" >> /etc/environment
source ~/.bashrc
```

## 4. Setup User Accounts

In the terminal run:

```
sudo nano $CATALINA_BASE/conf/tomcat-users.xml
```

and add the following lines between the `<tomcat-users>` and `</tomcat-users>` open and close tags:

```
<!-- user manager can access only manager section -->
<role rolename="manager-gui" />
<user username="manager" password="_SECRET_PASSWORD_" roles="manager-gui" />

<!-- user admin can access manager and admin section both -->
<role rolename="admin-gui" />
<user username="admin" password="_SECRET_PASSWORD_" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui" />
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 2):

The link of the mirror provided in tecadmin site ***might not always work***. It gave 404 when I tried to download.

However, **the archive always works**. Open [***this***](http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.0.M11/bin/) link and download your preferred file. There is a documentation at the end of this page, explaining what are the purpose of each of the files.

For ubuntu users:

1. download the .zip/.tar.gz file from the archive,
2. extract it in your desired location,
3. update manager roles in {tomcat-base-dir}/conf/tomcat-users.html(see [***this***](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access) link for help).

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the perfect installation guide here:

[Easy Guide to Install Apache Tomcat 9 on Ubuntu 18.04 / 16.04 LTS Server](https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-apache-tomcat-9-ubuntu-18-04-16-04-server/)

> NOTE:
>
> This link has instructions for `apache-tomcat-9.0.10.tar.gz`. Be sure to follow instructions for the latest version.
>
> Remember that after after downloading and extracting `apache-tomcat-9.0.*.tar.gz` change the folder name from `apache-tomcat-9.0.*` to `tomcat` or just move all contents of `apache-tomcat-9.0.*.tar.gz` to `/opt/tomcat/`